# Receiving truncated javascript from request

Tags: javascript, html, truncated

I am working on a page at http://yourworldclocks.juplo.com/. This page loads a `/incl/tzs.js` where a `initNames();` function is defined and called in document-ready. FireBug says that this function is not defined, but it is in `tzs.js`.

When I look at the request, it returns 465,6 KB, but `tzs.js` on the server is 701.82 KB. I see no other error messages.

I have never seen that bug before. I have reset my provider's account and reloaded the site, but I still get the same issue. Anyone knows what is happening? Any ideas? Thanks.

**P.S.:** The site was working well 15 mins ago.

Comment: is `tzs.js` being requested?

Comment: The difference between the value of `Content-Length` header and the actual filesize may differ if transport uses compression (deflate, gzip, etc.). Did you actually verify that the entire file content is received with request that loads your JS? Are you checking the console for any errors whyle tzs.js loads? If there's one, that may result in later functions report 'not-defined'.

Comment: Everything works fine from my end.

Comment: Works perfect in Chrome.

Comment: I have: <script src='./incl/tzs.js' type="text/javascript"></script> followed by <script src='./incl/ywc.js' type="text/javascript"></script> which contains the document-ready call.

Comment: Btw, works for me in Chrome and FF (Linux)...

Comment: Marcell: When I ask FireBug to display the content, it is indeed truncated and the end of tzs.js is not displayed

Comment: Ok, I have just restarted Firefox and the issue disappeared... Another heisen bug I guess. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting Firefox made the issue disappear. Don't know what caused it though.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered similar behaviour and dug in to find that this is a weirdness of HTTP headers. I was using nginx in my case; not sure what server you were on.
The thing is, for defining gzip compression to my resources, I had enabled compression as follows

        `# gzip settings
        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length  900;
        gzip_buffers  4 32k;
        gzip_types    application/x-javascript text/xml text/css application/json;
        gzip_vary on;
        # gzip settings end`

The important consideration here is the line `gzip_min_length  900;`.
This instructs nginx that if the content size is less than 900 bytes, do not compress that resource.

The file size in my case was 506 bytes (less than 900) so nginx did not compress it. But, it sent the `Content-Length` of the resource as if it *had* actually compressed it (566 bytes). (Yes the resource size actually increased on compression. This is to be expected of smaller files, which is why there is a `gzip_min_length` directive in the first place)

So to resolve this,I simply lowered the threshold of `gzip_min_length` to 100. Now nginx compresses the file (which bloats it slightly to 566 bytes), and sends the correct `Content-Length` header as well (566 bytes).

Hope this helps someone!